# Sitecore fast query filter by field exists, null

Tags: sitecore

Can I use XPath Builder under Developer Center inside Sitecore Shell to select all items below a node and filter it by if field exists, single line text field?
With a fast query (not limited by the Query.MaxItems setting)

for example somethings like: `fast://sitecore/content//*[@#my field# != '' ]`

But this query make no difference between empty and field does not exist, I want the empty ones in my result and not the items where the field not exsist.

Comment: Don't think its possible with sitecore query. You may have to use linq to sitecore instead.

Comment: I don't think is posible, why you don't query by template? You know all the templates that contains your field.

Comment: Right, by query the templates I can do my query.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an article talking about how to fix Fast query to search by field: http://www.agehrke.com/2014/12/fixing-sitecore-fast-query-querying-by-field-id/

Otherwise something like this would work:

```
   Item[] items = Sitecore.Context.Database.SelectItems("/sitecore/content//*[@MyField != '']")
```

Or use an index:

```
public IEnumerable<SearchExample> Example()
        {
            using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(GlobalIndex).CreateSearchContext())
            {
                var query = context.GetQueryable<SearchExample>()
                    .Where(item => item.MyField != null)                    
                    .ToList();
                return query;
        }
    }
```